# Why is Haven's discovery important?

Tags: nt.number-theory, continued-fractions

Today my attention was caught by one of those little stories that appear when you open a certain browser: [an inmate achieved a number theoretic breakthrough](https://phys.org/news/2020-05-inmate-math-discoveries.html)
It is about continued fractions and I would like to understand the implications of the discovery.

So my question is whether someone could provide details about the mathematical aspects of the discovery, especially what further progress number theorists expect from the result and/or the author.

Comment: Have you read the paper? It is available for free on Springer: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs40993-020-0187-5 . It says "... similar relations are more hard to give and we think that other ways should be used for approaching the problem for general values of determinants. However, the results of this paper could help in finding a solution to the general case." and "The results obtained in this paper can also be used to determine the linear fractional transformation of certain Hurwitzian and Tasoevian continued fractions, as well as studying their leaping convergents."

Comment: @Favst yes, I have read it, but I would also like to know whether any other areas of number theory, that "only" utilize those continued fractions as a tool, will benefit from the result.

Comment: It isn't that important per se. It is a nice result which may be used for later work. But it wouldn't be getting this level of attention if some regular math PhD had written it. The attention is to a large extent due to the author in question.

Comment: Before we apply our prejudices, note that (as the story goes) the author has more mathematical desire and initiative than training, in my view.  This is close to an amateur success story.  Gerhard "With Moral: Keep On Trying" Paseman, 2020.06.22.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman that's the reason why I put the focus of my question on the mathematical result and not on the circumstances under which they were obtained or on moral aspects. Of course the story is remarkable and the therapeutic aspects of mathematics are yet a different universe to explore...